# Firebasestorage Collect Data and Save in to Firebasestorage

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-storage

Now i can select image from gallery&camera and can crop it too. but i can't save Image to firebase when I click on save button.

**Here this is my activity.kt&xml**

**This is AccountSettingsActivity.kt**

```
`package com.example.pureeducationapp
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.canhub.cropper.*
import com.example.pureeducationapp.Model.User
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_account_settings.*
import kotlin.collections.HashMap


class AccountSettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser
private var checker = ""
private var imageUri: Uri? = null
private var myUrl = ""
private var storageProfilePicRef: StorageReference? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_settings)

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
    storageProfilePicRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Profile Pictures")


    change_image_text_btn.setOnClickListener {
        checker = "clicked"
        launchCropImage()
    }

    logout_btn.setOnClickListener {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()

        val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, SignInActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

    save_inFor_profile_btn.setOnClickListener {
        if (checker == "clicked") {
            uploadImageAndUpdateInfo()
        } else {
            updateUserInfoOnly()
        }
    }


    userInfo()


}

private val cropImage = registerForActivityResult(CropImageContract()) { result ->
    if (result.isSuccessful) {
        val uriContent = result.uriContent
        Log.d("uriContent", uriContent.toString()) // getting called
        profile_image_view_profile_frag.setImageURI(uriContent)
    } else {
        val exception = result.error
    }


}

private fun launchCropImage() {
    cropImage.launch(
        options {
            setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
        }
    )
}

private fun updateUserInfoOnly() {

    when {
        full_name_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Please insert full name first.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        username_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Please insert username first.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        bio_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Please tell about yourself first.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        else -> {
            val userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

            val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
            userMap["fullname"] = full_name_profile_frag.text.toString()
            userMap["username"] = username_profile_frag.text.toString()
            userMap["bio"] = bio_profile_frag.text.toString()

            userRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).updateChildren(userMap)

            Toast.makeText(this, "Account Information has been updated.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()

            val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}

private fun userInfo() {
    val userRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(firebaseUser.uid)

    userRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                val user = snapshot.getValue<User>(User::class.java)

                Picasso.get().load(user!!.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile)
                    .into(profile_image_view_profile_frag)
                username_profile_frag.setText(user!!.getUsername())
                full_name_profile_frag.setText(user!!.getFullname())
                bio_profile_frag.setText(user!!.getBio())
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

        }

    })
}

private fun uploadImageAndUpdateInfo() {

    when {
        imageUri == null -> Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Please select your image first.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        full_name_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Please insert full name first.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        username_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Please insert username first.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        bio_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Please tell about yourself first.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()

        else -> {

            val fileref = storageProfilePicRef!!.child(firebaseUser!!.uid + ".jpg")

            val uploadTask: StorageTask<*>
            uploadTask = fileref.putFile(imageUri!!)
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>> { task ->
                if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                    task.exception?.let {
                        throw it
                    }
                }
                return@Continuation fileref.downloadUrl
            }).addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<Uri> { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val downloadUrl = task.result
                    myUrl = downloadUrl.toString()

                    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

                    val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                    userMap["fullname"] = full_name_profile_frag.text.toString()
                    userMap["username"] = username_profile_frag.text.toString()
                    userMap["bio"] = bio_profile_frag.text.toString()
                    userMap["image"] = myUrl

                    ref.child(firebaseUser.uid).updateChildren(userMap)

                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Account Information has been updated.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()

                    val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                }
            })
        }


    }
}
}`
```

**This is ActivityAccountSettings.XML**

```
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AccountSettingsActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout_notifications"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/notifications_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/close_profile_btn"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/close"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/save_inFor_profile_btn"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/save_edited_info"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>




    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image_view_profile_frag"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_bar_layout_notifications"
            />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/change_image_text_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_image_view_profile_frag"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/full_name_profile_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/change_image_text_btn"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Fullname"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username_profile_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/full_name_profile_frag"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Username"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bio_profile_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username_profile_frag"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="About me"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/delete_account_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bio_profile_frag"
        android:text="Delete Account ?"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/red"


        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logout_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Log out"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />



</RelativeLayout>`
```

**Here is Result**
[https://media.giphy.com/media/fd31Toh3KDIhyo9sv1/giphy.gif]

It's seem like didn't collect data image right ? (if i'm not misunderstand).
so,

**How can i fix this solve ?**

**How to collect data image and save it to firebase storage when click save button ?**

Best regards

How can i solve this problem ? Help please.

Comment: Did you enabled and added rules for Storage module from firebase console?

Comment: yes im already enabled

Answer (score 0):

So if i understand correctly, you can get image and crop it successfully, so your firestore upload method not working. Here is mine working example and i do not use StorageTask, it's simpler:

```
        else -> {

            val fileref = storageProfilePicRef!!.child(firebaseUser!!.uid + ".jpg")

            fileref.putFile(imageFileURI!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                taskSnapshot.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl
                    .addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                    val downloadUrl = uri.toString()

                    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

                    val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                    userMap["fullname"] = full_name_profile_frag.text.toString()
                    userMap["username"] = username_profile_frag.text.toString()
                    userMap["bio"] = bio_profile_frag.text.toString()
                    userMap["image"] = downloadUrl

                    ref.child(firebaseUser.uid).updateChildren(userMap)

                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Account Information has been updated.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()

                    val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                    }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.e(
                    this.javaClass.simpleName,
                    exception.message,
                    exception
                )
            }       
        }
```